# How to get transaction info of a public key hash in a plutus smart contract?

Tags: plutus, smart-contract, pkh, transaction-history

Given a PubKeyHash (pkh) how can I get the history of that pkh's transactions from within a plutus smart contract?

Answer (score 1):

Plutus only validates a pending transaction given a datum, redeemer and script context, which includes tx inputs. The only way you could potentially provide that kind of information is through the datum or maybe reference inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out plutus does not support this yet (if your reading this in the future it might be out of date -> please check the timestamp).